# Quanta plus not supported?

Tags: web-design

I'm using ubuntu since very long time, developing web applications.
After update to version 11.10 I Was very disapointed to see that **Quanta Plus** is NO LONGER SUPPORTED in this version.

Quanta is only one so powerful web development tool in linux distributions, after You removed it, I can't work under ubuntu.

Did You just forgot to put Quanta in repos ?

Please advice, Thanx !

Comment: "After You removed it" The users of this site are not necessarily the developers or packagers. They are volunteers that give help, not necessarily support and package programs.

Answer (score 1):

The last version of Quanta Plus was released [3,5 years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quanta_Plus), it's [website](http://quanta.kdewebdev.org/) seems to be down at the moment so it seems the project is pretty much dead. Which is a pity, I used to use it.

Your options are either to find a replacement (kate is quite good as an editor, though maybe has less features for html/php coding) - or be a real man and see what it takes to compile it from the source. If you do this, maybe you'll become a new maintainer...

UPD: Actually, the last commit in the Quanta's repository seems to be almost [4 years ago](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quanta/files/quanta/) - I'm not even sure there ever was a KDE4 version... most likely it remained a KDE3 application, which makes it surprising it was still working in 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

The Quanta's KDE mailinglist archives: http://lists.kde.org/?l=quanta&r=1&w=2

A topic (Any progress on Quanta for KDE 4?) : http://lists.kde.org/?t=130763123700002&r=1&w=2

Comment: Interesting reading, thanks. Looks like there was some almost-recent effort to port Quanta to KDE4: http://gitorious.org/kdevelop/quanta, but that page is also marked as "obsolete"

Comment: ... and as the Quanta is depending the deprecated KDE 3.5 libs (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdelibs/+bug/794513) the Quanta was removed from the repositories when the KDE 3.5 libraries were removed.

Comment: Thanks for quck reply. Searching the internet I found Komodo Edit (http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) which for PHP/CSS editing is better than Quanta Plus.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unhappy with the upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 because a lot of things got broken, not the least of which is Quanta Plus. Also kdenlive and a few others. I have work to get done and compared to Quanta everything else is a toy.

I'm seriously considering down-grading to 11.04 so I can get my productivity tools back!!

Answer (score 0):

I can say for sure that there is a way to install and run Quanta Plus on 11.10 as I have been using it on 11.10 for about 4 weeks. I am trying very hard to remember what I had to do to install it but it was something very simple like checking the unchecked boxes in repository list under the 2nd tab. Although I have just done this on a brand new installation and it is not working. Perhaps the first time I got it to work is when I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 so the program was still there, but if you do a fresh install then it is not there as the KDE packages are depreciated so I don't think there is an answer. I am going to try `komodo-edit` and see how that works but like others I am super disappointed that Ubuntu have not kept the excellent program `Quanta` in their new version. Especially when so many of us rely on using it every day for our jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Quanta can be installed easily on ubuntu. Just follow the instructions given here

http://www.binarytides.com/install-quanta-plus-ubuntu-12-10/