# How can I copy quanta from 11.04 ubuntu to 11.10 install?

Tags: 11.10, unsupported-packages, app-install

I did a fresh install of 11.10 and found that, Quanta is no longer available, as the kde packages are no longer supported, but I copied the .kde folder to the new install and the folders inside include `/share/quanta/` and all the quanta files. I was wondering if someone could tell me, how to run the program or make a launcher and would this work to use "Qunata plus", as I don't like the alternatives. I need this program for my work.

When Upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10 you can still install and use Quanta but not on a fresh install. I need to know what to copy besides the .kde folder which is in the `home/user/username/.kde`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Earlier**

A link: [Quanta plus not supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66716/quanta-plus-not-supported)

**KDE 3 version of Quanta**

The Quanta is depending the deprecated KDE 3.5 libs /2/. They are removed from the 11.10 repositories /1/. You need to get them back.

**KDE 4 version of Quanta**

The development of the new version of the Quanta seems to have stalled.

**KDE 3.5 Desktop**

The Trinity /3/, /4/ is offering the KDE 3.5 desktop and support to the "old" KDE 3 apps.

**A Quanta installation example**

http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?57703-Need-help-to-find-a-WYSIWYG-Web-editor&p=290490#post290490

**Links:**

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdelibs/+bug/794513
2. http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/quanta
3. http://www.trinitydesktop.org/
4. http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/11/02/1726228/kde-35-fork-trinity-releases-first-major-update